# The sms commands or codes to send manually to windows phone

Tags: find-my-phone

is there any way to send manually sms command to my windows phone to unsilent it or triangulate its position? I can't use windows' platform because my country code is not listed so I can right down my telephone number. Please, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: No

The long answer:
As you said the commands are just ordinary SMS, here's what one might look like:
Sky#AgAx4dgZm1vlVMX0uvECq5PPcjKDw48YRZorwjmTMdJOeQj6ixvaclPyMHPtS2U5Y/ZfZQ==

So technically its possible. However... That string contains no (visible) information on what the phone is supposed to do. Which makes it really hard for you to create it manually :/

I'll update if I find something exciting on the topic :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this.  It would require SMS intercept capability, and the ability for a user program to do system wide type command.  Or have that kind of functionality built in.  If you need your phone number, you can just call another phone and see what the number is?

Comment: I don't think that's true actually. When you use the special functions on windowsphone.com what actually seems to happen is that a hidden SMS is sent to your phone which instructs the phone to do one of the tasks. The OP would like to mimic this SMS from some other device so he could get his position and so forth without needing to use the Microsoft SMS service which isn't available in his country.